# Re-rending when update property of object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, reactive

I have an `fileArray` array to hold all the *File Object* in a **Vue** 2 app. When I update a property of an *File Object* using `this.set` as recommended, it will not re-render (to toggle "active" class). However, it would work if the array holds normal *Object* such as `fileArray = [{name: "John"}, {name: "Jacob"}]` but not the *File Object*

Code

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in fileArray">
    <a-card :class="item.active ? 'active' : ''">
    <img :src="item.imageUrl" @click="handleSelect(index)" />
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fileArray: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
   beforeUpload(file) {
     // Add file object into array
     this.fileArray.push(file)
     return false
    }
  },
  handleSelect(index) {
   if (this.fileArray[index]) {
     // Update object property inside an array with this.$set but it won't re-render
     this.$set(this.fileArray[index], 'active', !this.fileArray[index].active)
   }
  }
}
```

- Some how the code below will help to re-render but spread operator doesn't work with File

```
beforeUpload(file) {
     // Add file object into array
     this.fileArray = [...this.fileArray, {...file}]
     return false
    }
},
```

- Temporary solution to re-assign the array so it will re-render

```
handleSelect(index) {
   if (this.fileArray[index]) {
     this.$set(this.fileArray[index], 'active', !this.fileArray[index].active)
     this.fileArray = [...this.fileArray]
   }
}
```

Please help if you experienced this.

Answer (score 0):

This code don't work ?:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="item in fileArray">
    <a-card :class="{ active : item.active }">
    <img :src="item.imageUrl" @click="item.active = !item.active" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `:key` attribute on your v-for element, so vue doesn't know which of the nodes should be updated. Try adding a hash/unique id to pass to the key attribute, or use index as a workaround.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in fileArray" :key="item.imageUrl">
  <a-card :class="item.active ? 'active' : ''">
  <img :src="item.imageUrl" @click="handleSelect(index)" />
</div>
```

I chose imageUrl above as I figured it might be unique for each image. If they have no unique identifiers, 'index' could be used as well.

If that doesn't work, you can manually force an update by binding the key to something you replace on each update, or in the final line of defense use the method in this link below:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Controlling-Updates